# Language switcher does not show flags or languages

Tags: php, joomla

[image]I am trying to show the Language switcher. i had created Language switcher in back end and assign to position-7 there is visual the title of Language switcher and also drop-down but there are no any language in drop-down and not a flags. [image]

Comment: Have you set up your site for multilingual? 
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Setup_a_Multilingual_Site

Comment: yes i have setup two language there

Comment: It looks something is missing, as there is no link for multilanguage status as there in the bottom left - https://www.joomlashack.com/images/blog/joomla-how-tos/installing-multilingual-site/24_look_around_your_multilingual_site.png

Comment: So what is the solution ?

Comment: and i can't Re-install this  because there are lot number changes.

Comment: I would suggest to go through once again with that document. You might have missed something like creating default menus for language or publishing plugin.

Comment: Okay Thanks for your time. let me check it once.